How do I make a List visible in a ScrollView?
I want to show an array of elements preferrably in a list within a scrollview, however seems when added to the body of a scrollview the list becomes invisible regardless of the content.
Code example:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            showSheet.toggle();
        }, label: {
            Text("Toggle")
        }).sheet(
            isPresented: $showSheet,
            content: {
                ScrollView { 
                    Text("Visible")
                    List {
                        Text("Invisible")
                        Text("Also invisible")
                    }
                    Text("Also visible")
                }
            }
        )
        
        Text("Visible")
        ScrollView {
            List {
                Text("Invisible")
                Text("Also invisible")
            }
        }
        Text("Also visible")
    }
}


So if this is intentional, what's the reason behind it? Or if it's not intentional, how should I make the list visible?

try giving your List a size, eg .frame(height: 333). You can also use GeometryReader to size the ScrollView  based on the sheet size.
